# Opening links in a new tab with javascript stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I have some code on my tumblr blog that makes it so the links in the "notes" div open in a new tab — it works fine but once i click "Show More Notes" (which loads more links), it stops working on those links. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#notes a").attr("target","_blank");
});
</script>
```

**Here is what tumblr says on this issue**: "Notes are paginated with AJAX. If your theme needs to manipulate the Notes markup or DOM nodes, you can add a Javascript callback that fires when a new page of Notes is loaded or inserted"

**tumblrNotesLoaded(notes_html)** "If this Javascript function is defined, it will be triggered when a new page of Notes is loaded and ready to be inserted. If this function returns false, it will block the Notes from being inserted."

**tumblrNotesInserted()** "If this Javascript function is defined, it will be triggered after a new page of Notes has been inserted into the DOM."

Comment: Can you please add more details?

Comment: And why don't you set target attribute in HTML markup for those links?

Comment: @A.Wolff - he doesn because tumblr doesn't

Comment: Um, if you post the actual tumblr template code I am pretty sure this could be an easy fix inside the template, simply updating the note tags.

Comment: Updated the post with more info.

Comment: OK, so did you remove the link to your page also? If the code quoted below by @JaromandaX is inserted by Tumblr (ie outside of your template) which I almost certainly think it is, then you won't be able to manipulate it. You might be able to write your own function and wrap it in an ajaxComplete function. It's a bit clunky. Something like, $('.notes a').ajaxComplete(function(){ $(this).attr("target","_blank");  }); Needs testing.

Answer (score 1):

the newly loaded links wont have target set to _blank ... what you should do, when you've loaded the new links is execute

```
$("#notes a").attr("target","_blank");
```

again - as you've shown no code regarding the loading of these links, that's the best I can do

edit: I just looked at your page - I ***think*** this should do the trick

```
this.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('notes_loading_121152690941').style.display = 'block';
if (window.ActiveXObject) var tumblrReq = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) var tumblrReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
else return false;
tumblrReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (tumblrReq.readyState == 4) {
        var notes_html = tumblrReq.responseText.split('<!-- START ' + 'NOTES -->')[1].split('<!-- END ' + 'NOTES -->')[0];
        if (window.tumblrNotesLoaded)
            if (tumblrNotesLoaded(notes_html) == false) return;
        var more_notes_link = document.getElementById('more_notes_121152690941');
        var notes = more_notes_link.parentNode;
        notes.removeChild(more_notes_link);
        notes.innerHTML += notes_html;
        if (window.tumblrNotesInserted) tumblrNotesInserted(notes_html);
        // ************************************************
        $("#notes a").attr("target","_blank");
        // ************************************************
    }
};
tumblrReq.open('GET', '/notes/121152690941/lhtXynZtK?from_c=1433902641', true);
tumblrReq.send();
return false;
```

the added line is surrounded by `// ************************************************`

Comment: I think that code is inserted by Tumblr, so it cannot be changed

Answer (score 1):

You could set `target` attribute on `mousedown` delegated event, e.g:

```
$(function () {
    $('#notes').on('mousedown', 'a:not([target])', function () {
        this.target = "_blank";
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, i replaced the code with this and none of the links opened in new tabs.

Comment: Maybe because anchors already have a target attribute, so try replacing `a:not([target])` with `a`

Comment: Close, but you're setting the target too late. By the time your handler is run, the browser already decided that the link will open in the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('ol.notes').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    if (e.which > 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        return;
    }
    window.open(this.href);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This attaches an event handler on the notes container, making sure that it only gets clicks on `a` elements and that the clicks are not middle-clicks, alt-clicks, …

Once all of those superfluous clicks are filtered out, it simply opens a new tab via Javascript; there's no need to set `target="_blank"`